Whitelist of IPs for Power Automate SFTP
Has anyone been able to get SFTP in Power Automate to work where the server has an IP address filter?
I found this page that specifies the Outbound IP addresses:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/common/outbound-ip-addresses#power-platform
For the US, it lists 7 addresses plus one for Preview.
I added those to the filter, but still get Bad Gateway. It works when there is no IP address filter.
It also points to a downloadable list of IP addresses of which there are many more.
But when I ran a test against the SFTP server that had no IP address filter, the originating address was not in either list.
Some examples of where the SFTP came from were:
waws-prod-bn1-c5e6fc61.sip.p.azurewebsites.windows.net [20.85.70.164]
waws-prod-sn1-9ffb7728.sip.p.azurewebsites.windows.net [52.185.230.136]
They aren't in either list.

Please verify that the IPs you added are correct and check your firewall settings to ensure they allow traffic from those IPs. Additionally, consult the official Microsoft documentation for SFTP configurations. If the issue persists, consider reaching out to Microsoft support for further assistance.

This issue often arises when the outbound IP address used by Power Automate is not included in the whitelist on your SFTP serve
